# Unit Testing on Springboot WebClient with MockWebServer

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, junit5, mockwebserver

After searching around the net for few days, couldn't really find the resources I need for my use case as many of it are implemented in Java.

I have a service class that is calling external api, and I am trying to write unit tests on it with MockWebServer

```
@Service
class ApiService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var webClient: WebClient

    fun getApiResult(name: String): ResultDto? {
        return try {
           webClient
               .get()
               .uri("https://www.example.com/")
               .retrieve()
               .bodyToMono(Result::class)
               .block()
            catch {
               null
        }
    }
}
```

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
@MockitoSettings(strictname = Strictness.LENIENT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class ApiServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private lateinit var webClient: WebClient

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var mockApiService: ApiService

    private val mockName = "mockName"
    private val mockDetailDto = DetailDto(name = "mockName", age = 18)

    @Test
    fun canGetDetails() {
        mockWebServer.enqueue(
            MockResponse()
                .setResponse(200)
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .setBody(mockDetailDto))
        )

        mockApiService.getApiResult(mockName)
        val request: RecordedRequest = mockWebServer.takeRequest()

        // Assert statements with request
    }
}
```

However, I am getting `lateinit property webClient has not been initialised`. But if I were to use `@Spy` instead of `@Mock` for the webClient in my test, it will be making actual apis calls which is not the goal of unit test. My goal would be able to check the `request` for some of the details such as `GET` and its return value. Appreciate the community's help.

Answer (score 0):

By my opinion you not add some configuration, for resolve it automatically you can try make Integration Test for this. Like this

```java
@WithMockUser//if you use spring secutity
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
}
```

and make a test application for quickly loading environment

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true)//make loading is faster
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This way can load full context configuration like prod mode, of course only for called methods if you used `lazyInit = true`